# Z-buffer issue with BufferGeometry in ParticleSystem

Tags: javascript, three.js, particle-system

In my application I'm having troubles with the z-buffer. I have a ParticleSystem in which the dots have a texture to look like spheres. But there are two problems which I can't solve at the same time....

Either the spheres were sorted right in z-buffer but aren't transparent or they are transparent but not right sorted!

Please have a look at my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DS9U2/). (based on [this example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_particles_billboards_colors.html) from mrdoob)

In the original example all looks well. But as you can see in my fiddle, the texture is not transparent, so hiding parts of the particles behind it. I only changed from `Geometry` to `BufferGeometry`, because in my application I have to use this to avoid perfomance issues. You can switch between these two by changing my comments in the fiddle. And by switching between `Geometry` and `BufferGeometry` you can see that the z-buffer is breaking.

Somewhere in the internet I found this "solution":

```
depthWrite : false
```

which I added to the material. Then the particles look great but the z-buffer is not correct.
This is driving me crazy... anyway I found out that my type of Geometry is the problem.

So why is mrdoob's example not working with `BufferGeometry`? What can I do to get right sorted AND transparent particles in my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused. The texture is transparent, and remains so when switching to `BufferGeometry`.

What is happening, is that with `BufferGeometry`, the particles are not rendered in sorted order -- they are rendered in the order you specify in the buffer.

If you want to use `BufferGeometry`, you can set

```
material.alphaTest = 0.5.
```

Then, in your case, things should look fine.

three.js r.60

Comment: Thanks! But now the texture has artefacts. Can you please explain what `alphaTest`does? And this trick seems to work only during perspektive camera. I have a second, an orthographic camera, for a bird's eye view on my system, and there is the z-buffer still wrong. Do I have to do anything else for this camera?

Comment: The fragment is not rendered if the fragment alpha is less than `alphaTest`. You will have to make a new post and provide a live example if you are having additional problems. Saying it "has artifacts" or the buffer is "wrong" is not descriptive. I answered the question you posted here.